# Visual glitch when zooming in with TeXstudio

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texstudio

### Image

[image: TeXstudio glitch while zooming]

I have been getting this weird visual glitch when clicking on the pdf rendered by TeXstudio to zoom in. My drivers are up to date and MikTex is also updated.

### Question

Does anyone know what causes this glitch? Is there some fix or should I just wait for updates?

I am using the latest TeXstudio with MikTeX installed. I had always used Overleaf before so this is the first time I've come across something like this. I did **not** get this glitch when I tried zooming in with TeXworks so I think it might be something wrong with TeXstudio.

Comment: This is similar to https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/1773, which apparently is a Qt6-bug. That one seemed to be about included images though, not normal text/math. I'd suggest commenting on that issue, and ask if it could be the same problem.

Comment: Thanks Torbjørn, the workaround mentioned in that issue thread did work. I use 125% scaling. Switching display scaling to 100% makes the zooming work fine. I am uncomfortable with the lower zoom though so I'm trying to figure out how to switch to Qt5.

Comment: I assume you'd have to go back to the previous version, 3.1.2, of TeXstudio: https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/releases/tag/3.1.2

Comment: I just got it. The TexStudio download page has 2 options to download version 4.0.0 one with QT5 and one with QT6.

Comment: Oh right, hadn't noticed that. Sorry for the misinformation.

Comment: No problem. Switching to QT5 works perfectly now even with 125% scaling thanks a lot!

Comment: If someone doesn't want to download TexStudio again, `smdanjm` workaround in that Github page works great. I'll post it here:

`I am currently experiencing this issue. My workaround is to go to texstudio.exe right-click properties window>compatibility>"Change high DPI settings", check "Override high DPI scaling behavior." and set list item to "System". This method avoids having to change scaling systemwide. Program items are slightly bigger but glitch is no longer present.`